# Update in loop in loopback node js

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

In loopback I need to handle Patch in loop.
Whenever I try to patch a property, I may have to update the property in one or all the other records in the table/collection. I've been using `before save` hook and calling `updateInLoop` as shown below to update the other records.

```
module.exports = function(Model) {
    Model.observe('before save', async(ctx, next) => {
        if(ctx.Data) {
             updateInLoop(ctx.Data, Model);
        }
    });
}

const updateInLoop = async function(data, Model) {
    var modelDbData = await Model.find();
    for(let entity in modelDbData) {
        if(entity.property > threshold){
            entity.property = entity.property + 1;
            await Model.upsert(model);
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to be working fine if loop in `updateInloop` doesn't run more than once. Whenever the loop need to be run more than once, the code doesn't seem to be working as expected.

I found that the unexpected behavior is due to the `before save` hook being executed for every update action in loop. How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is definitely expected, if you make your increment statement easily recognizable you can prevent it from calling itself.

```
module.exports = function(Model) {
    Model.observe('before save', async(ctx) => {
        // if(ctx.Data) {


        let keys = ctx.Data ? Object.keys(ctx.Data) : undefined;
        // It is an increment if the length of its keys is 1 and that the key is property
        let isIncrement = (keys && keys.length === 1 && keys[0] === 'property');

        if (ctx.Data && !isIncrement) {
            updateInLoop(ctx.Data, Model);

        }
    });
}

const updateInLoop = async function(data, Model) {
    var modelDbData = await Model.find();
    for(let entity in modelDbData) {
        if(entity.property > threshold){
            // entity.property = entity.property + 1;
            // await Model.upsert(model);

            await Model.updateById(entity.id, {property: entity.property + 1});
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the expression ctx.Data && ctx.instance will always evaluate to be undefined as ctx.instance will be undefined in case of patch and ctx.data will be undefined in case of insert.

Comment: Damn, you're right.  Would `Data` ever contain a reference to the incremented property? You could use that to discriminate.

Comment: For the first iteration, `data` contains the incremented property. As the iteration proceeds, the `before save` hook gets triggered for each `upsert` and the `ctx` parameter in the hook changes too. Except the first iteration, data never contains the incremented property.

Comment: I've added a new discriminator to prevent the recursion.  It assumes that an increment statement has only one data property and that it is property.